# How to use MVC Contrib Grid to make better table?

Tags: mvccontrib

There are actually 2 question i want to cover in this topic.

1) Is there anyway to put table footer into a MVCContrib Grid? (tf)

2) Im writing a small code to display result image into a grid:

```
-----------------------------------
| I || I || I || I || I || I || I |
-----------------------------------
| I || I || I || I || I || I || I |
-----------------------------------
| I || I || I || I || I || I || I |
-----------------------------------
| I || I || I || I || I || I || I |
-----------------------------------
```

I represent Image, this will make as a table to maintain equal width.. But is there anyway of doing this with MVCCOntrib particularly or Asp.net MVC View?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For item #1:

> Out of the box there’s no built in way
>   to do this, but there are some
>   extensibility points you can hook into
>   if you want to add this functionality.
>
> If you create a custom GridRenderer
>   that inherits from HtmlTableGridRender
>   then you could override the
>   RenderGridEnd method and generate the
>   appropriate HTML in there.
>   - Jeremey Skinner

From comments in http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/03/01/mvccontrib-grid-part-5-the-action-syntax/

On #2:

As long as you wrap your images in a way with styling to enforce the same size for each image (if the images are of different sizes to begin with) this should be doable.